# Swift 3 Generic Type usage

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

First, I have a protocol:

```
public protocol ContentList {
//...
}
```

and some `struct`s:

```
public struct Post: ContentList {
//...
}
public struct Essay: ContentList {
//...
}
```

then I have a subclass of `UITableViewController`:

```
open class MainTableViewController<T: ContentList>: UITableViewController {
    // ...
    func getData() -> [T] {
        retrun ...
    }
}
```

the UI part of this class, `MainTableViewController`, was defined in `Main.storyboard`, so I did this:

```
let kMainTableViewControllerIdentifier = "MainTableViewController"
let listController = (self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: kMainTableViewControllerIdentifier) as? MainTableViewController<Post>)!
listController.dataSourceType = .post
```

and I got some error:

```
Unknown class _TtC5Elias23MainTableViewController in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x1af463db8) to 'Elias.MainTableViewController<Elias.Post>' (0x101907af8).

 Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x1af463db8) to 'Elias.MainTableViewController<Elias.Post>' (0x101907af8).
```

I have no ideas about how to solve this so far. so I need some help.

Comment: I've been trying to set this up in Xcode but I'm getting a segmentation fault from the compiler, so I haven't been able to test what I'm about to suggest. I think you might need to set the class of the view controller in your Storyboard to either `MainTableViewController<Post>` or `MainTableViewController<Elias.Post>`.

Comment: @GaryMakin thx. but I'm using generic type which means the `<Post>` part from `MainTableViewController<Post>` could be different, like `<Essay>` or `<App>` if they are confirm to `ContentList` protocol.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I'm not sure you can do what you want to do. The instance of the view controller has to have a specific type, not either this or that.

Comment: Move the generic type into a class that you use in the view controller as a helper. You can customise the way the view controller works by changing the helper instance.

Comment: @GaryMakin yes, that's right. maybe I should try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your view controller is defined as a MainTableViewController in the storyboard as well!

[image]